# Parsing incomplete / doubled / damaged JSON String

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, parsing

In Python, how would one retrieve information from a incomplete or "overcomplete" JSON string?

Example (incomplete):
`msg = '{"MESSAGE": {"MESSAGE_SIZE": "2230", "IMAGE_NUM'`

Example (overcomplete):
`msg = '{"MESSAGE": {"MESSAGE_SIZE": "2230", "IMAGE_NUMBER": "16227"}}{"MESSA'`

Specifying the key `MESSAGE_SIZE`, I want to retrieve the integer `2230`.

The position of the key inside the string is mutable.

One working solution I found is the following (ugly) piece of code. I'm sure there are better solutions though:

```
key = "\"MESSAGE_SIZE\":"
len_start_idx = 0
len_str = ""
len_int = 0

# Find position right after key
start = msg.find(key)
msg = msg[start+len(key):]

# Find the first value digit after the key
for c in msg:
    if not c.isdigit():
        len_start_idx += 1
    else:
        break

msg = msg[len_start_idx:]

# Append value digits until no more digits are found
for c in msg:
    if c.isdigit():
        len_str += c
    else:
        break

len_int = int(len_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, there is a npm-module to [untruncate json files](https://github.com/dphilipson/untruncate-json) but I couldn't find anything similar for python.

It shouldn't be too complicated to implement one though. This should work in most cases (also closing lists):

```
import json
import re

closing_chars = {
    '{': '}',
    '[': ']'
}

def close_structs(json_string):
    stack = []
    for char in json_string:
        if char in ['{', '[']:
            stack.append(char)
        elif char in ['}', ']']:
            stack.pop()
    for open_struct in stack[::-1]:
        json_string += closing_chars[open_struct]
    return json_string

def untruncate_json(json_string):
    while True:
        try:
            d = json.loads(json_string)
            return d
        except Exception as e:
            if "Expecting ':' delimiter" in repr(e):
                json_string += ": null"
            elif "Unterminated string starting at" in repr(e):
                json_string += '"'
            elif "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes" in repr(e) \
                or "Expecting value" in repr(e):
                json_string = re.sub(r'[:,]\s*$', '', json_string)
            elif "Expecting ',' delimiter" in repr(e):
                json_string = close_structs(json_string)
            else:
                print(json_string)
                raise e

msg = '{"MESSAGE": {"MESSAGE_SIZE": "2230", "IMAGE_NUMBER": "16227", "TE'
d = untruncate_json(msg)
# getting the desired value:
print(int(d["MESSAGE"]["MESSAGE_SIZE"]))
```

Edit: handling cases "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes" and "Expecting value" + stripping all kinds of whitespace chars with `re.sub` (in order to include `\n`)